# Add watcher to dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

At some point in time of the component’s work, one of its values ​​from the primitive turns into an object. This object is dynamically assigned fields with values. It is necessary to track the change in these values.

Simplified code to reproduce the problem:

```js
const fields = ['name', 'age'];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: function() {
      console.log('Global: Value changed');
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.value = '111';
    this.value = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      this.value[field] = '';
    });

    this.$watch('value', callback, { deep: true });
    function callback() {
      console.log('Callback: Value changed');
    }

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.value.name = 'Max';
      this.value.age = 30;
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical line is `this.value = ...`. That's the point where the object will be made reactive and all properties need to exist at that point.

Here I've tweaked that section to add the properties before assigning the object to `this.value`.

```js
const fields = ['name', 'age'];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: function() {
      console.log('Global: Value changed');
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.value = '111';

    const value = {}

    fields.forEach(field => {
      value[field] = '';
    });

    this.value = value;

    this.$watch('value', callback, { deep: true });
    function callback() {
      console.log('Callback: Value changed');
    }

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.value.name = 'Max';
      this.value.age = 30;
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Alternatively you can use `this.$set` to set them later: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set.

Comment: Thank. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

`Vue.$set(object, key, value)` can be helpful here:

```js
const fields = ['name', 'age'];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler: function(value) {
        console.log('Global: Value changed', value);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let value = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      value[field] = '';
    });

    this.$set(this, 'value', value);

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.value.name = 'Max';
      this.value.age = 30;
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is called reactivity Caveat

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

so to solve this issue you can import vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

and then where you want to change values of an object

```
fields.forEach(field => {
  //this.value[field] = ''; // instead of this
    Vue.set(this.value, 'field', '')
});
```

OR

```
this.$set(this.value, 'field', '')
```